# How can I uncheck the checked row of a table only if the column value matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Actually I am looking to uncheck the checked row of a table only if the column value of the row matches to my value(value that i am passing). When I check the row from table 1 it binds into table 2.

So with the below script, when I delete a row from the "table 2", I am fetching the column (item code) value of row to be deleted from "table 2" and pass it to another table "table1". Now I want to compare the selected rows column value of "table1". If the column (Item code) value of table 1 matches to "item code" that I am passing, I want to uncheck the row.

But with the below code when I try to delete a row from table 2. it unchecked all the selected rows from table 1. So how can I modify my script to uncheck only only row (matched value row)?

Any help appreciated.

**HTML Table**

**Table 1**

```
<table id="order-table" name="order-table">
<tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Medication</th>
    <th>Max Issue Limit</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>X</th>
    <th>Unit Price</th>
    <th>=</th>
    <th>Totals</th>
    <th>Item Code</th>
</tr>
<tbody id="contacts">
    <tr class='odd'>
        <td><input type='checkbox' class='single-checkbox' checked></td>
        <td class='product-title'>itemName</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td class='qty'>2 </td>
        <td class='times'>X</td>
        <td class='rate'>10.00</td>
        <td class='equals'>=</td>
        <td class='date-total'>20</td>          
        <td class='med'>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='odd'>
        <td><input type='checkbox' class='single-checkbox'></td>
        <td class='product-title'>itemName</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td class='qty'>2 </td>
        <td class='times'>X</td>
        <td class='rate'>10.00</td>
        <td class='equals'>=</td>
        <td class='date-total'>20</td>          
        <td class='med'>2</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Table 2**

```
  <table id='peopleTable' class='table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped'>
  <thead>
  <tr><th style='width:475px;'>Item Name</th>
  <th>Actual Amount</th> 
  <th>Bill Amount</th>
  <th>Item Code</th> 
  <th></th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody style='height:135px;overflow:auto'>
    <tr>
      <td class='name'>Item Name</td>
       <td class='price'>25.00</td>
       <td>24.00</td>
       <td class='midlist'>1</td>
       <td>
       <button type='button' onclick='deletePerson(this);' class='btn btn-default'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' /></button>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Here is my script**

```
 function deletePerson(ctl) {

    $(ctl).parents("tr").remove();
    var sum = 0.00;        
    $('.price').each(function () {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    if (sum > 0.00) {
        var elem = document.getElementById("grandtotal"); // Get text field
        elem.value = sum;
        var eleminfo = document.getElementById("ActualAmount"); // Get text field
        eleminfo.value = sum;
        var elemen = document.getElementById("grandtotalclaim"); // Get text field
        elemen.value = sum;
        var elemenfees = document.getElementById("ClaimAmount"); // Get text field
        elemenfees.value = sum;
    }

    else {
        sum = 0.00
        var elem = document.getElementById("grandtotal"); // Get text field
        elem.value = sum;
        var eleminfo = document.getElementById("ActualAmount"); // Get text field
        eleminfo.value = sum;
        var elemen = document.getElementById("grandtotalclaim"); // Get text field
        elemen.value = sum;
        var elemenfees = document.getElementById("ClaimAmount"); // Get text field
        elemenfees.value = sum;

    }

    var value1= $(ctl).parents("tr").find('.midlist').text();

    var tableControl = document.getElementById('order-table');

    var count = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked', tableControl).length;

    $('input:checkbox:checked', tableControl).each(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.med').each(function () {
            var te = $(this).text();                
            if (te == value1) {
                alert("matched");
                $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Not Matched");
            }
            
        })
    });
    
}
```

Comment: can you post your html code in your question ?

Comment: `te = value1` is performing an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: Html code posted for your reference @HimanshuUpadhyay

Comment: Changed to compariosn `te==value1` @skirtle